# Why most of the javascript frameworks use object literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, prototype, object-literal

Why most of the javascript frameworks uses object literals instead of constructors or constructors with prototypes?Will it be non standard ,if somebody uses constructors with prototypes in a new framework.What are the advantages of object literals over constructors with prototypes?

Comment: They are two completely different things...  Maybe some code examples might clarify your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the need of the programme you're writing and the way you want to maintain the code base.

When you have objects which get instantiated a lot with shared properties and methods it could be more efficient memorywise to use a constructor and fill its prototype.

When the code is more or less a singleton it is probably more efficient to just make an object and fill it with some methods.

If you would like more information about "patterns" and what they can mean to you you could check out http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Or if you like a regular (e-)book i would recommend http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do

Comment: There are some frameworks which make use of the prototype approach, the first one that pops in my head is (no pun intended) "Prototype".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean how jQuery automatically defines the jQuery/$ objects? simple answer ... it's easier that way. Can you imagine how confusing jQuery would be for new users if they had to include the following two lines in every single page?

```
var jQuery = new jQuery();
var $ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about using `{}` vs `new Object()` and `[]` vs `new Array()`.

The literal version in both cases is often faster (of course this depends on the browser). You also get the added advantage of being able to define properties in an object or items in an array from the onset. This makes the code more lightweight and readable.

```
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
// vs.
var o = new Object();
o.a = 1;
o.b = 2;
o.c = 3;
o.d = 4;

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
// vs.
var a = new Array();
a.push(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

**Edit**: I made performance tests for [objects](http://jsperf.com/object-literals-vs-new-object) and [arrays](http://jsperf.com/literal-array-vs-new-array). For me, object literals were actually a bit slower in Chrome. Array literals were much faster, however. The syntax is still preferred, though.

Answer (score 0):

But if your instantiating the object several times then prototype uses less memory because you're not recreating the entire object with all its methods.

Prototype is nice because it allows you to create a new method on the fly and have all intances of that object use. Syntactically it's ugly and I prefer object literal. But if you're building a massive app and performance is a big issue then prototype is probably the way forward no?